# kannada words are displaying as question marks in firefox browser

Tags: php, html, mysql, firefox

I am trying to display kannada words in mozilla browser on Ubuntu 12.04 lts connecting through the MySql.

I have used collation utf-8 general ci and used `header('Content-type:text/html; charset=utf-32');` php code in php.

When I tried to retrieve the words from database and display it on the firefox browser it is displaying as question marks...

Please help.

Comment: Have you check whether the kannada language insert into the database?

Answer (score 0):

The character encoding that you declare in a header must be the same as the actual encoding. It seems that these differ radically (UTF-32 vs. possibly UTF-8). Find out the actual encoding and declare it.

Don’t use UTF-32 on web pages. Firefox was the last major browser that supported it, and the [support was removed](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=604317) in 2011.